# OpenSSL build odd behaviour

Tags: build, console, openssl, console-redirect

Its kinda an odd story. I'm trying to build the openssl library. Well, it is not the first time I'm doing it and until now it was fine. however, I've desided to add a build configuration to TeamCity (actually the problem has nothing to do with TeamCity)to build all my third parties libraries on-demand. So, I created a step with common set of openssl build commands:

perl Configure VC-WIN64A

ms\do_win64a.bat

nmake /d /f ms\ntdll.mak

... and the build failed while assembling the very first asm file. So I ran same commands in VS2012 x64 command prompt and the build succedeed, as expected. It took a while untill I figured out that the problem is in output redirection. Teamcity redirects output from build step to the teamcity build log, so did I by adding ">1.txt" to "nmake /d /f ms\ntdll.mak" command, and the build failed. I would say it is somewhat unexpected reason for build to fail.
So far, I've tried:

- Building the same from VS2010 command prompt with redirection,
  failed.
- Building the same from VS2010 command prompt without
  redirection, succeded.
- Building the same from VS2010/VS2012 command
  prompt with redirection to file and forcing redirection to CON (nmake
  /d /f ms\ntdll.mak >CON >1.txt) failed.
- Googling for "nmake problems
  when console output is redirected" - nothing
- Googling for "openssl
  build problems when console output is redirected" - nothing

My setup
 - Win2008R2, virtual machine.
 - VS2010, latest updates
 - VS2012, Update 1

Actual error:
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\BIN\amd64\ml64.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
ml64.exe complains about the asm file stating it should end with "END" statement. It does, but...
Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, looks like it is a (not) well known problem. http://www.mentby.com/Group/openssl-users/cant-redirect-console-log-during-windows-build.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, since the problem is in perl and writing files to stdout and then redirecting it you have to change following files to build x64 version:

1. crypto\aes\asm\aes-x86_64.pl
2. crypto\bn\asm\modexp512-x86_64.pl
3. crypto\bn\asm\x86_64-gf2m.pl
4. crypto\bn\asm\x86_64-mont.pl
5. crypto\bn\asm\x86_64-mont5.pl
6. crypto\md5\asm\md5-x86_64.pl
7. crypto\modes\asm\ghash-x86_64.pl
8. crypto\rc4\asm\rc4-md5-x86_64.pl
9. crypto\rc4\asm\rc4-x86_64.pl
10. crypto\sha\asm\sha1-x86_64.pl
11. crypto\sha\asm\sha512-x86_64.pl
12. crypto\whrlpool\asm\wp-x86_64.pl
13. crypto\x86_64cpuid.pl
14. engines\asm\e_padlock-x86_64.pl

you have to open these files and change all "open STDOUT "whateverfile"" to something like "open my $asmfile "whaeverfile"", then take care of string concatenation (only in x86_64cpuid.pl) and then print it to the file instead of STDOUT, something like "print $code" to "print $asm $code"
and of course, dont forget to close the file, in another words change the "close STDOUT" to "close $asmfile"

Obviously when building target other than x64 one will have to change another set of files.

Will try to communicate it to openssl maintainer.